# UWP windows 10 store and windows 10 mobile store

Tags: windows, uwp

I am building an application targeting windows 10 desktop and mobile both some functionality like back button functionality is different for each device mobile device use hardware back button while desktop use title bar back button option 
do i have to make 2 different projects for each of device ?

Comment: the event is the same for both uses of back buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can have just one. Originally the back button handling on phone was done separately using the Mobile Extension SDK, but in later builds before the final release of Windows 10 this back button handling was refactored to be universal for all device families, although the back button is displayed on a different place in each.

Basically the only thing you need is to wire up the event globally:

```
Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += 
   App_BackRequested;
```

To learn more, see the [official MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt465734.aspx).

Comment: tell me some thing i want my app to play a require page on landscape orientation in mobile but i dont want to do this in desktop or tablet mode how can i do this kindly share some code detail thanks for your help..

Comment: Hi, this is a separate question, create a new one please and send me a link :-) .